# knockout cascading data binding not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 2 dropdowns. I want to load the second dropdown on selection of the first dropdown. The first dropdown loads fine but the second dropdown doesn't get loaded. There are no console errors.

HTML

```
<select data-bind="
 options: $root.availableTutorials,
 value: $root.selectedTutorial,
 optionsCaption: 'Choose tutuorial...',
 event:{ change: $parent.onFirstChange }">
</select>

<select data-bind="
 options: $root.availableTutorials2,
 value: $root.selectedTutorial2,
 optionsCaption: 'Choose tutuorial2...'">
</select>
```

JS

```
        viewModel.selectedTutorial = ko.observable();
        viewModel.selectedTutorial2 = ko.observable();

        viewModel.availableTutorials = ko.observableArray([
            'Academic', 'Big Data',
            'Databases', 'Java Technologies',
            'Mainframe', 'Management',
            'Microsoft Technologies', 'Mobile Development',
            'Programming', 'Software Quality'
        ]);

        viewModel.onFirstChange = function () {

            alert('first changed');

            viewModel.availableTutorials2 = ko.observableArray([
                'Academic', 'Big Data',
                'Databases', 'Java Technologies',
                'Mainframe', 'Management',
                'Microsoft Technologies', 'Mobile Development',
                'Programming', 'Software Quality'
            ]);

        }
```

On selection of the first dropdown, it does show the alert 'first changed' but doesn't bind data. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `availableTutorials2` should be initialized as an empty observable array from the start (i.e. `viewModel.availableTutorials2 = ko.observableArray([])`). In your change handler, you can load its values by writing `viewModel.availableTutorials2([ "Academic", /* etc */ ])`

Comment: @user3297291 I tried that but still no luck. Same result

Comment: I posted my suggestion as an answer so you can see it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For knockout to be able to update the options, it needs to have an observable array available from the start (at the time of `ko.applyBindings`). To update options, you write to that observable array by calling it (`myObsArray([])` instead of `myObsArray = []`)

```js
const viewModel = {};

viewModel.selectedTutorial = ko.observable();
viewModel.selectedTutorial2 = ko.observable();

viewModel.availableTutorials = ko.observableArray([
    'Academic', 'Big Data',
    'Databases', 'Java Technologies',
    'Mainframe', 'Management',
    'Microsoft Technologies', 'Mobile Development',
    'Programming', 'Software Quality'
]);
viewModel.availableTutorials2 = ko.observableArray([]);

viewModel.onFirstChange = function () {
    viewModel.availableTutorials2([
        'Academic', 'Big Data',
        'Databases', 'Java Technologies',
        'Mainframe', 'Management',
        'Microsoft Technologies', 'Mobile Development',
        'Programming', 'Software Quality'
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
 options: $root.availableTutorials,
 value: $root.selectedTutorial,
 optionsCaption: 'Choose tutuorial...',
 event: { change: $root.onFirstChange }">
</select>

<select data-bind="
 options: $root.availableTutorials2,
 value: $root.selectedTutorial2,
 optionsCaption: 'Choose tutuorial2...'">
</select>
```

I'd also suggest not using the `change` event, but using a `subscribe` or `computed` that uses `selectedTutorial` as a trigger to load the second dropdown's values.